# Function template parameterized by an allocator that is used to construct containers of different types

Tags: c++, allocator

I want a function `foo` along these lines

```
template <class T, class Alloc>
void foo(T param, Alloc a) {
    vector<int, Alloc<int> > vect_of_ints;
    list<float, Alloc<float> > list_of_floats;
    do_something()
}

std::allocator a
foo(42, a);
```

This fails, I think because `std::allocator` is not a well defined type till it has been sepcialized for a particular type. Is it possible to do what I want to do, but in some other way.

Comment: Look up "template template parameters" (not a typo? the word template is used twice).

Comment: @san My earlier comments are obsolete (I've deleted them). The point is that `std::allocator` is a template, so you need to accept it as a template template parameter: `template <template <class> class Alloc>`.

Comment: One question: You create the allocator, `a`, outside the function. Do you want it like that? The problem is you'd really have to create one `std::allocator<int>` and one `std::allocator<float>` and pass them both to `foo` so it can use them. Why don't you create the allocators inside of `foo`?

Comment: @jogojapan My `foo` needs to be able to work with an allocator that the client of `foo` will provide. So its really not in my control. All I want is to use the same allocator for different datatypes. But the datatypes that I use internally, I do not want to expose outsude of the function.

Comment: But do you really need the caller do provide the allocator object? Doesn't suffice if the caller provide the allocator _type_?

Comment: @jogojapan Yes allocator type will work too, but cant figure out how to. I thought `std::allocator` is still a type untill you specialize it with `std::allocator<int>` etc. But dont know how would I pass the allocator type to `foo` that takes other arguments as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have one instance of the allocator (a) and expect it to work for 2 different types. You can however, use the allocator generic type (a template template parameter), and specialize it in your foo() in two different ways.
You are not using "a" on your foo() anyway.

```
template <template<class> class Alloc, class T>
void foo(T t1, T t2) {
    vector<int, Alloc<int> > vect_of_ints;
    list<float, Alloc<float> > list_of_floats;
    do_something()
}

// UPDATE: You can use a function wrapper, and then the compiler will be
// able to figure out the other types.
template<class T>
void foo_std_allocator(T t1, T t2)
{
    foo<std::allocator, T>(t1, t2);
}


int main()
{
    //std::allocator a;
    //foo<std::allocator>();
    foo<std::allocator, int>(1, 2);

    // in the call below, the compiler easily identifies T as int.
    // the wrapper takes care of indicating the allocator
    foo_std_allocator(1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One question: If `foo` takes other arguments, how would I pass the allocator type to it.

Comment: @san you can pass it the same way, it doesnt matter. foo<std::allocator, template_parameter2>(real_parameter1, real_parameter2);

Comment: @Nick Thanks again. Could you make the declaration of foo and the call consistent. I am all but ready to accept the answer

Comment: @san No, if you have a template template parameter the compiler can't infer the parameter type (since the instance of a template template is a template itself). And then you have to explicitly indicate every subsequent type (int in this case) on the call. You coud do a wrapper, check my update.